# Delphi. Преобразовать строку в дату используя полный/длинный формат

Tags: delphi, winapi

Есть задача написать парсер текстовых логов стороннего приложения, код и настройки которого менять нельзя.

К сожалению, приложение использует формат даты из настроек Windows. Его разработчик сообщил, что вызывает WinAPI-функцию `GetDateFormat`.

Мой парсер запускается на той же машине в тот же день, то есть получить те же настройки Windows легко.

На одной из машин формат установлен «`d MMMM yyyy 'г.'`», то есть в том месте, где должна быть дата я получаю подстроку вида «`19 января 2023 г.`».

Функция `System.SysUtils.StrToDateTime` падает в ошибку, так как ожидает увидеть строку из цифр, пробелов и `FormatSettings.DateSeparator`, но не букв.

Даже если я сам разложу эту строку на составляющие, то есть сложность с тем, что «`января`» = `1`, ведь в `FormatSettings.LongMonthNames` название месяца хранится в именительном падеже («`Январь`»).

Вероятно названия месяцев в родительном падеже можно получить через WinAPI `GetLocaleInfo` с флагом `LOCALE_RETURN_GENITIVE_NAMES`

Вопрос: Есть ли в стандартной библиотека Delphi или в WinAPI функция преобразования строки в дату в соответствии с `LongDateFormat`, то есть функция обратная к WinAPI `GetDateFormat`?

Comment: Если вы получили логи с другой машины, то там мог стоять ЛЮБОЙ формат, вплоть до Тайского с годом по Китайскому календарю. Хорошо если так - т.е. явно видно, а мог записаться и 2022/12/02 и сиди гадай, это месяц-день или день-месяц.

Поэтому Единственный надежный вариант - при записи дату в строку преобразовывать своими силами, желательно по стандарту типа ISO-8601.

Comment: Ясно, тогда действительно нужно искать какой-то метод из WinAPI (и надеяться что оно есть, а не сторонняя прога сама склоняет что-то на свой вкус). Я внес это уточнение в вопрос, чтобы все вместе было.

Comment: "то не понятно, что «января» = 1" - ну что тут непонятного. Такую функцию элементарно написать самостоятельно. Если "января", то 1, если "февраля", то 2 и тд.\

Comment: @Эникейщик как эникейство подойдет конечно, но вы же понимаете что нужен системный подход? )

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, а если региональные параметры поменяются? Если нет возможности согласовать формат и привести его к виду, не зависящему от региональных настроек ОС, то, возможно, следует рассмотреть вариант внешней библиотеки? Если не ошибаюсь, в .NET есть [парсер даты](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-7.0). Можно попробовать создать dll и вызывать из Delphi.